# Django: AttributeError: 'UniqueConstraint' object has no attribute 'fields_orders'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model called "Employment" in my app, which references two models called "User" and "Company". In the Employments table in the database, there is a composite index on the two foreign keys preventing the same user from having two employments with the same company. I am trying to represent this composite index in Django using the UniqueConstraint class, but it is throwing an error which I cannot find any documentation for.

This model usually works perfectly fine. However, when I add the UniqueConstraint to the model's indexes, the server throws an error. I've looked at the documentation for [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint), as well as the rest of Django's documentation, but could not find any mentions of the error I receive. I've also tried replacing 'User_ID' and 'Company_ID' with 'user' and 'company' in the fields argument for UniqueConstraint, but I obtained the exact same error.

Not sure if this is relevant to the issue, but I'm running the Django server with Docker in a python:3.6 container with Django version 2.2.

Here is the Employment model:

```
from django.db import models
from app.models import User, Company

class Employment(models.Model):
    Employment_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user          = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='User_ID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company       = models.ForeignKey(Company, db_column='Company_ID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Employments"
        indexes = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['User_ID', 'Company_ID'],
                                    name='Employment_User_Company_UNIQUE') # server works fine without this
        ]
```

When I start my Django server, I get the following output:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 31, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1254, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1565, in _check_indexes
    fields = [field for index in cls._meta.indexes for field, _ in index.fields_orders]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1565, in <listcomp>
    fields = [field for index in cls._meta.indexes for field, _ in index.fields_orders]
AttributeError: 'UniqueConstraint' object has no attribute 'fields_orders'
```

If anyone has experienced this error or knows of a workaround, I would be very grateful for your insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined this in the <s>`indexes`</s> parameter, but this should be in the [**`constraints`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints) attribute. `indexes` contains, as the name suggests, the list of indexes defined on the table. `constraints` on the other hand contains the constraints that should be enforced.

```
class Employment(models.Model):
    Employment_ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='User_ID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, db_column='Company_ID', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Employments"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['User_ID', 'Company_ID'],
                name='Employment_User_Company_UNIQUE'
            )
        ]
```